# Python script scheduler

Tags: python, selenium, parsing, heroku, pythonanywhere

everyone!
Now I am trying to run my python parser (web scraper) every hour (better every 10 minutes).
I tried:

```
Windows scheduler (task scheduler)
pythonanywhere
heroku
```

Heroku:
I have a error:

```
2020-11-23T09:05:02.707582+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/chrome/webdriver.py", line 73, in __init__
2020-11-23T09:05:02.707740+00:00 app[web.1]:     self.service.start()
2020-11-23T09:05:02.707741+00:00 app[web.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/common/service.py", line 83, in start
2020-11-23T09:05:02.707894+00:00 app[web.1]:     os.path.basename(self.path), self.start_error_message)
2020-11-23T09:05:02.707952+00:00 app[web.1]: selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'chromedriver' executable needs to be in PATH. Please see https://sites.google.com/a/chromium.org/chromedriver/home
2020-11-23T09:05:02.707953+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2020-11-23T09:05:02.811239+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2020-11-23T09:05:02.851583+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to crashed
2020-11-23T11:01:39.422624+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=zoho-parser.herokuapp.com request_id=2135d635-fa47-47e5-900f-71d19afe1032 fwd="188.64.166.28" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2020-11-23T11:01:40.985460+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=zoho-parser.herokuapp.com request_id=806a1d26-3541-4cd5-ab46-d73288e3e589 fwd="188.64.166.28" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
```

(I deploy the app Succesful)

My buildpacks:
heroku/python, https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-google-chrome, https://buildpack-registry.s3.amazonaws.com/buildpacks/heroku/google-chrome.tgz, https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-chromedriver

Config Vars:
CHROMEDRIVER_PATH=/app/.chromedriver/bin/chromedriver
GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN=/app/.apt/usr/bin/google-chrome

pythonanywhere:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/AndrewCreator/Parser.py", line 27, in <module>
    driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=CHROMEDRIVER_PATH, options = chromeOptions)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'options'
```

In windows task scheduler I successfully create a task, Script work! :)

But only when I am working on the computer :((

My platform - widows 10.

My scripts:

Parser.py:

```
#Parser Zoho
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
from selenium.webdriver.support import expected_conditions as EC
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import WebDriverWait
from selenium.webdriver.chrome.options import Options
import yagmail
import os

from CheckLetter import CheckLetter
from SetValue import SetValue


url = 'https://help.zoho.com/portal/en/community/zoho-crm'
CHROMEDRIVER_PATH = r'C:\Users\admin\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python38\site-packages\ChromeDriver\chromedriver.exe'
yag = yagmail.SMTP("arshostak@gmail.com", 'MyPassword')
to = "arshostak@gmail.com"
subject = "New question"
body = ["Someone asked about ", ". Here is the link:"]
#driver
chromeOptions = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
chromeOptions.binary_lacation = os.environ.get("GOOGLE_CHROME_BIN")
chromeOptions.add_argument("--headless")
chromeOptions.add_argument("--disable-dev-shm-usage")
chromeOptions.add_argument("--no-sandbox")
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=str(os.environ.get('CHROMEDRIVER_PATH')), options = chromeOptions)
driver.get(url)

element = WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(
    EC.presence_of_element_located(
        (By.CSS_SELECTOR, "div.TopicListLeftContainer__section")
    )
)

isFind = False

for idx, q in enumerate(driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('div.CommunityListItem__wrapper')):
    question = q.find_element_by_tag_name('a')
    shortDiscription = q.find_element_by_css_selector('div.CommunityListItem__description')
    link = question.get_attribute("href")

    shortDiscriptionText = shortDiscription.text
    questionText = question.text
    letter = str(questionText) + ". " + str(shortDiscriptionText)
    letter = letter.replace(" ", "")

    FountProgramm = SetValue(CheckLetter(letter, "Zoho"), questionText, link)
    if (FountProgramm != False):
        yag.send(to, subject, body[0] + FountProgramm + body[1] + "\n" + str(link))
        print(link)
        isFind = True
    pass
pass

driver.quit()

#Parser StackOverflow
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

url = "https://stackoverflow.com/questions"

res = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(res.text, "html.parser")
questions = soup.select(".summary")

for que in questions:
    QustionName = que.select_one('.question-hyperlink').getText()
    QuestionLink = "https://stackoverflow.com/" + que.find('a').get('href')
    letter = QustionName.replace(" ", "").lower()

    FountProgramm = SetValue(CheckLetter(letter, "StackOverflow"), QustionName, QuestionLink)
    if (FountProgramm != False):
        yag.send(to, subject, body[0] + FountProgramm + body[1] + "\n" + str(link))
        print(QuestionLink)
        isFind = True
    pass
pass

if (isFind == False):
    print("False")
pass
```

CheckLetter.py:

```
def CheckLetter(Letter, MainPlatform):
    triggers = GetTriggers(MainPlatform)
    for platform in triggers:
        for trigs in triggers[triggers.index(platform)]:
            if str(type(trigs)) != "<class 'list'>":
                name = str(trigs)
                continue
            pass
            requiredNum = len(trigs)
            fountNum = 0
            for trig in trigs:
                if (trig.lower() in Letter.lower()):
                    fountNum += 1
                pass
            pass
            if (fountNum >= requiredNum):
                return name
            pass
        pass
    pass
    return False
pass

def GetTriggers(Platform):
    if (Platform == "Zoho"):
        triggers = [["Twilio", ["twillio"], ["twilio"], ["tvilio"], ["tvillio"]],
                    ["Quickbooks", ["Quickbooks"], ["Quick-books"], ["QBO"]],
                    ["Xero", ["Xero"]]
                    ]
        return triggers
    pass
    if (Platform == "StackOverflow"):
        triggers = [["Twilio", ["twillio", "Zoho"], ["twilio", "Zoho"], ["tvilio", "Zoho"], ["tvillio", "Zoho"]],
                    ["Quickbooks", ["Quickbooks", "Zoho"], ["Quick-books", "Zoho"], ["QBO", "Zoho"]],
                    ["Xero", ["Xero", "Zoho"]]
                    ]
        return triggers
    pass
    return False
pass
```

SetValue.py:

```
import gspread
from oauth2client.service_account import ServiceAccountCredentials
from pprint import pprint
from datetime import datetime

spreadsheetName = "Questions"
scope = ["https://spreadsheets.google.com/feeds",'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',"https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.file","https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive"]
creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("creds.json", scope)
client = gspread.authorize(creds)
sheet = client.open(spreadsheetName).sheet1

data = sheet.get_all_records()
column = sheet.col_values(4)

def SetValue(platform, name, link):
    if (platform == False):
        return False
    pass
    for value in column:
        if (value == str(link)):
            return False
            break
        pass
    pass

    insertRow = [str(datetime.now())[:-7],platform, name, link]
    sheet.insert_row(insertRow, 2)
    return platform
pass
```

Also, I have creds.json (with my private kays...)

Also, I don't want to run my python script on my pc (some times google block my searching)

If anyone can solve one of the errors or suggest to me another good platform (It can be paid, but better is free) I will be really happy
(I tried to run my script for about 1.5 weeks :(

Comment: Heroku is telling you Chromedriver isn't on the path - have you done anything to install it in that environment?

Comment: hi @jonrsharpe. No, I just add chromeDriver to my pc path (system properties > environment variables > user variables for admin > path > my path to chromedriver). How can I tell Heroku where my path?

Comment: The code running in Heroku can't access Chromedriver running on your local machine, you need to install the appropriate software (Chrome, Chromedriver) *on the dyno*.

Comment: Real thanks you @jonrsharpe, I will try to do it! :)

Comment: But I already have dyno: "web python Parser.py" What should I white in dyno? :(

Comment: My dyno type is "free"

Comment: What makes you think that will install chrome and/or chromedriver? Have you done any research around installing things in the dyno?

Comment: No :( I will find some tutorials to learn about it. It will be good if you will say me what I 
should write in dyno... (if you know, if not I will google it...) Thanks!

Comment: On PythonAnywhere you need to contact support@pythonanywhere.com and ask for enabling beta virtualization features to be able to use Chromedriver.

Comment: @caseneuve Thanks, I will try to do it!